# jQuery Mobile - intercept paypal form submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, paypal

I've got a jQuery Mobile website with a PayPal custom button. The button sits inside PayPal form (which obviously I shouldn't temper with). The problem is that when I hit the button, there is no indication that something is happening - so I though to intercept the form submit and show some "loading" mask.

Is there anyway to do so? or other ideas how to show that something is happening?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what verion of jquerymobile are you using ? in the latest stable version (1.0.1) they changed the `$.mobile.pageLoading();` to `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();`

Comment: Well, that fixed that :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an event to the submit event, but make sure you maintain the usual behavior:

```
$('form.paypal').submit(function(){
    // Show loading gif
    return true;
});
```

*(Of course you should change `form.paypal` for the appropriate reference)*

Comment: Thanks - that does the job of intercepting.

Comment: The problem is with showing the loading mask. it just doesn't work. I'm using $.mobile.pageLoading();

Comment: Did you check out what @dali said? Try using `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();`